# Joomla 3 module h3 title span

Tags: php, joomla, module

I can change the colour of the first word in my module titles.
It can be done by adding a span to the first word of the title.

Below modules.php code works for this OK.

**BUT**

In Joomla admin when I create a class for Module Class Suffix it is not created for the module in the front end.

Something is missing from module.php to enable Module Class Suffix that is created in Joomla admin

This is the code I have for templates/mytemplate/html/modules.php

```
    <?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Administrator
 * @subpackage  Templates.protostar
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2013 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

/**
 * This is a file to add template specific chrome to module rendering.  To use it you      would
 * set the style attribute for the given module(s) include in your template to use the     style
  * for each given modChrome function.
 *
 * eg.  To render a module mod_test in the submenu style, you would use the following     include:
 * <jdoc:include type="module" name="test" style="submenu" />
*
 * This gives template designers ultimate control over how modules are rendered.
 *
 * NOTICE: All chrome wrapping methods should be named: modChrome_{STYLE} and take the     same
 * two arguments.
 */

/*
 * Module chrome for rendering the module in a submenu
 */
function modChrome_xhtmlwithcolor($module, &$params, &$attribs)
{
$headerLevel = isset($attribs['headerLevel']) ? (int) $attribs['headerLevel'] : 3;
if (!empty ($module->content)) : ?>

<?php if ($module->showtitle) : ?>
<h<?php echo $headerLevel; ?>><?php
$title = $module->title;
$title = split(' ', $title);
$title[0] = '<span>'.$title[0].'</span>';
$title= join(' ', $title);
echo $title;
?></h><?php echo $headerLevel; ?>>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php echo $module->content; ?>

<?php endif;
}
?>
```

In the index.php template module position I have

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="bottom-1" style="xhtmlwithcolor" />
```

Can someone help or advise with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The `moduleclass_sfx` is passed in to your `modChrome_xhtmlwithcolor ()` as part of the `&$params` variable. To use it in your PHP you would use something like this:

```php
htmlspecialchars($params->get('moduleclass_sfx'))
```

Normally you would tend to wrap your module in a `<div>` to package it all up nicely for applying CSS, using DOM manipulation etc.

So you might have:

```php
echo "<div class=\"" . htmlspecialchars($params->get('moduleclass_sfx')) . "\">";
... your code ...

echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Hey cppl
From one Aussie to another
Thankyou
That Worked

Comment: Glad it helped, don't forget to mark the answer correct when you get the chance :D